# Weka Question: Which cluster do this Iris attributes belongs to?

Tags: weka

I'm totally new into Weka and data science, I got an assignment to detect which of the following Iris attributes (SW, SL, PW, PL) belongs to which cluster? can you assist me? Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcR2O.png)

Answer (score 0):

The iris dataset that comes with Weka has **three** classes (Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor, Iris-virginica).

If you want to see how well clusters determined by your cluster algorithm align with the class labels, you need to select `Classes to clusters evaluation` in the Weka Explorer or via the `-c <class_att_index>` option on the command-line.

The following command uses `SimpleKMeans` with three clusters on the iris dataset that comes with Weka (`-c last` uses the last attribute as class and performs clusters to classes evaluation):

```bash
java -cp weka.jar weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans -N 3 -c last -t data/iris.arff
```

Which will result in this output:

```
=== Clustering stats for training data ===


kMeans
======

Number of iterations: 6
Within cluster sum of squared errors: 6.998114004826762

Initial starting points (random):

Cluster 0: 6.1,2.9,4.7,1.4
Cluster 1: 6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3
Cluster 2: 6.9,3.1,5.1,2.3

Missing values globally replaced with mean/mode

Final cluster centroids:
                           Cluster#
Attribute      Full Data          0          1          2
                 (150.0)     (61.0)     (50.0)     (39.0)
=========================================================
sepallength       5.8433     5.8885      5.006     6.8462
sepalwidth         3.054     2.7377      3.418     3.0821
petallength       3.7587     4.3967      1.464     5.7026
petalwidth        1.1987      1.418      0.244     2.0795


Clustered Instances

0       61 ( 41%)
1       50 ( 33%)
2       39 ( 26%)


Class attribute: class
Classes to Clusters:

  0  1  2  <-- assigned to cluster
  0 50  0 | Iris-setosa
 47  0  3 | Iris-versicolor
 14  0 36 | Iris-virginica

Cluster 0 <-- Iris-versicolor
Cluster 1 <-- Iris-setosa
Cluster 2 <-- Iris-virginica

Incorrectly clustered instances :   17.0     11.3333 %
```